# Select number of photos upload in folder and view and delete in folder using php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, file

Hii Everyone,

Here I want to upload maximum of 250 images in single folder.Initially If user selects number of photos like 100.Below should show 100 div image box and If div box 5 click and image upload and after upload it should view image and on image tab delete icon will show and it will delete image from folder.Initially I tried this with simple code like below.

View Page:

```
<?php if($filecount>0){ ?>
  <div class="photos">
    <div id="images">
        <a href=# data-lightbox="roadtrip">
        <?php 
          $filename = substr($images[0], strrpos($images[0], '/') + 1);   
echo '<a href="'.$images[0].'" target="_blank"><img src="'.$images[0].'" style="width:250px;height:250px" /></a><br/>';
?>
    <a href="#" class="del_photo" style="color:#C20B0B;font-size:20px;" onclick="theFunction('<?php echo $filename; ?>','<?php echo $gallery_type; ?>','<?php echo $folder_name; ?>');"><i class="fa fa-remove"></i></a>

    </div>
</div>


  <?php } else { ?>
 <div id="imgContainer">
  <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="image_upload_demo_submit.php" method="post" name="image_upload_form" id="image_upload_form">
    <div id="imgArea">
          <img src=""></img>
      <div class="progressBar">
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="percent">0%</div>
      </div>
      <div id="imgChange"><span>Upload Photo</span>
        <input type="file" accept="image/*" name="image_upload_file" id="image_upload_file" onchange="upload_img();">
      </div>

    </div>
  </form>
         </div>
  </a>
    <?php } ?>



function upload_img()
{
         var gallery_type = '<?php echo $gallery_type; ?>';
         var folder_name = '<?php echo $folder_name; ?>';
         $.ajax({
      url: "upload_image_admin.php?folder_name=" +folder_name+ "&id="+gallery_type,
      type: "POST",
      data: new FormData($('#image_upload_form')[0]),
      contentType: false,
      cache: false,
      processData:false,
      success: function(data){
       location.reload();
        },
        error: function(){}           
     }); 
         }
```

JQUERY file

```
$(document).on('change', '#image_upload_file', function () {
var progressBar = $('.progressBar'), bar = $('.progressBar .bar'), percent = $('.progressBar .percent');

$('#image_upload_form').ajaxForm({
    beforeSend: function() {
    progressBar.fadeIn();
        var percentVal = '0%';
        bar.width(percentVal)
        percent.html(percentVal);
    },
    uploadProgress: function(event, position, total, percentComplete) {
        var percentVal = percentComplete + '%';
        bar.width(percentVal)
        percent.html(percentVal);
    },
    success: function(html, statusText, xhr, $form) {   
    obj = $.parseJSON(html);  
    if(obj.status){   
      var percentVal = '100%';
      bar.width(percentVal)
      percent.html(percentVal);
      $("#imgArea>img").prop('src',obj.image_medium);     
    }else{
      alert(obj.error);
    }
    },
  complete: function(xhr) {
    progressBar.fadeOut();      
  } 
}).submit();    

});
```

Backend (save folder) PHP file

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['id']))
{
    $gallery_type = $_GET['id'];
$folder_name = $_GET['folder_name'];
$valid_extensions = array('jpeg', 'jpg', 'png', 'gif', 'bmp'); // valid extensions
$path = "$folder_name/$gallery_type/images/";
}
else
{
$folder_name = $_GET['folder_name'];
$valid_extensions = array('jpeg', 'jpg', 'png', 'gif', 'bmp'); // valid extensions
$path = "$folder_name/images/";
}

if(isset($_FILES['image_upload_file']))
{
 $img = $_FILES['image_upload_file']['name'];
 $tmp = $_FILES['image_upload_file']['tmp_name'];

 $ext = strtolower(pathinfo($img, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

 $final_image = $img;

 if(in_array($ext, $valid_extensions)) 
 {     
  $path = $path.strtolower($final_image); 

  if(move_uploaded_file($tmp,$path)) 
  {
    echo "Image Uploaded";
  }
 } 
 else 
 {
  echo 'invalid file';
 }
}

?>
```

If I do like this I cant use single code for all div I should repeat same code for similarly like 250 divs and i want to create same jquery file for 250 divs 250 PHP files is there any easy way to do single code upload and view based on user selection  code so that code reusability will work and users folder in correct way.Reduce bandwidth.Please anyone help me to resolve this problem.
Below I share screenshot which I tried now.

[image]

From above picture you can understand.I can upload image seperately

Comment: how could you create `div` like 100s divs??

Comment: We can create on selection like user selects 100 for loop wil create 100 container's right

Comment: so you have a single form inside of 100+ divs right?

Comment: Yes @karthi. Is there any easy way

Comment: okay think this way may be its a hint for you, in case each div have a form every form have a action with same php file. now its possible i hope u

Comment: Again I want to code for each form acton sepearte pages right.I just want to reduce the code size can u understand

Comment: u said divs from `for` loop stmt. then what ? you just write once it will create it 100s

Comment: I am not 100% sure what your main issue is, but it sounds to me that you have one image/div working but you want all the divs working but don't want an inflated jQuery? If that is the case, you have to classes (so not the id like `#image_upload_form`) to do it. You would use a combination of a class name and `$(this)` to focus on the current div...Anyway, if this is not what you mean, then I don't really understand your issue.

Comment: Ya obsolutely.But how can select number of images can user upload